# Cannot set up dual monitor on TweinView model

Tags: xorg, hdmi, multiple-monitors

I want to connect an external monitor to my laptop via HDMI, external and built-in monitor are both 1920x1080. However, if I chose to expand screen, the total resolution will be 1920x1080 instead of 3840x1080. Tried to edit xorg.conf, but failed. How can I solve this problem?

Thank you for any help.